# If a set on a metric space is finite, then there exists a $c$ such that $d(x,y) > c, \forall x,y$, $x \neq y$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If a set on a metric space is finite, then there exists a $c$ such that $d(x,y) > c, \forall x,y, x \neq y$

Intuitively true, but how to prove this result?

Comment: This is not true! You mean "$\forall x,y$ in the set, $x\neq y$". Then it's correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "intuitively true"? If you can't prove it, expressing the intuition is a good first step.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Consider the set of all $d(x,y)$ such that $x\ne y$: it’s a finite set of positive real numbers, so ...

Comment: My brain has stopped

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows: Every finite set of reals has a smallest element.